# Same request sent to Squid, but getting 400 Bad Request error when using masscan

Tags: http, squid, http-status-code-400

I have a hello.txt file with the following contents:

```
GET http://www.google.com/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
```

Using netcat it works:

```
cat hello.txt | nc 212.8.251.116 62138
```

But when I use masscan I get 400 error:

```
# bin/masscan 207.180.212.139 -p62138 --banners --source-port 61000 --hello-file[62138] hello.txt

Starting masscan 1.0.6 at 2019-09-06 12:48:57 GMT
 -- forced options: -sS -Pn -n --randomize-hosts -v --send-eth
Initiating SYN Stealth Scan
Scanning 1 hosts [1 port/host]
Discovered open port 62138/tcp on 207.180.212.139
Banner on port 62138/tcp on 207.180.212.139: [title] ERROR: The requested URL could not be retrieved
Banner on port 62138/tcp on 207.180.212.139: [http] HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\x0d\x0aServer: squid/3.5.27\x0d\x0aMime-Version: 1.0\x0d\x0aDate: Fri, 06 Sep 2019 12:48:59 GMT\x0d\x0aContent-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8\x0d\x0aContent-Length: 3548\x0d\x0aX-Squid-Error: ERR_INVALID_URL 0\x0d\x0aVary: Accept-Language\x0d\x0aContent-Language: en\x0d\x0aX-Cache: MISS from de8g.t1ip.com\x0d\x0aX-Cache-Lookup: NONE from de8g.t1ip.com:62138\x0d\x0aConnection: close\x0d\x0a\x0d
```

However using wireshark I see the sent content is the same:

[image]
[image]

I made a diff of sent data in hex and it is the same.

Why does one of them cause error if the request is the same?

Comment: first you are using an optionnal syntax (absolute url in location) which may not be supported on all instances, than you are requesting a domain ( `www.google.com`) which is maybe not hosted on that host. I'm pretty sure you can configure squid to reject unhosted domains with an error 400. There're a lot of configurations options in squid, so differing behaviors, and your two examples are not on the same IP.